# Enable inputs after disabled

Tags: javascript, button, input, disabled-input

I want to Enable all this group of disabled inputs when clicking on `<button class="btn_modifier">MODIFIER</button>`. See below my inputs:

```
stock_array.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.choix_type == "1") {
        content1 +=
            `<tr>
            <div class="show">
        <td><input type="text" class="input_stock" value="${element.nom}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input_stock" value="${element.quantite}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="input_stock" value="${element.prix_achat_ht}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="input_stock" value="${element.prix_vente_ht}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="input_stock" value="${element.marge_ht = element.prix_vente_ht - element.prix_achat_ht}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="input_stock" value="${element.prix_ttc = element.prix_vente_ht * 1.2}" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input_stock" value="${element.degre}" disabled  /></td>
        <td>
        </div>
            <div class=btn_div>
                <button class="btn_modifier">MODIFIER</button>
                <button class="btn_delete">X</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>`
        ba.innerHTML = content1;

    }
}
```

I already try this :

```
let modifier = document.querySelector(".btn_modifier");
let able = document.querySelector(".input_stock");
modifier.addEventListener("click", function () {
    able.disable = false;
})
```

Comment: So on modifier button click you want to enable all input fields with class input_stock?

Comment: You are changing the attribute `disable` which is incorrect, it should be `disabled`. Also, you are using `querySelector` which would only get the 1st element that matches the query, use `querySelectorAll` and loop over the results.

Comment: @DaCurse - Just modify with your comment with: ` let modifier = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_modifier"); let able = document.querySelectorAll(".input_stock"); modifier.addEventListener("click", function () { if (able.disabled = true) { able.disabled; } else { able.disabled = true } })` but there is an error message "Uncaught TypeError: modifier.addEventListener is not a function at affichage (script.js:168)" –

Comment: @navnath - Yes .

Comment: @Jorge_RM by `document.querySelectorAll(".btn_modifier");` you are selecting all buttons whose has class `btn_modifier`. If you want to add eventListener to all those buttons you could do `[...modifier].forEach.addEventListener`But then what you want to do with it? disable add inputs which are not disabled and enable all inputs who are currently disabled

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with the class `input_stock` (or `getElementsByClassName`), and enable each one of them using a loop:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input_stock');
for (const input of inputs) {
    input.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let modifier = document.querySelector(".btn_modifier");

modifier.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let able = document.querySelectorAll(".input_stock");
  // converts NodeList to Array
  [...able].forEach(a => a.disabled = false);
})
```